# I have 5 folders (each contain about 200 RGB images), I want to use "Principal Component Analysis" for image classification

Tags: components, prediction, pca, principal

I have 5 folders (which represent 5 classes, and each contain about 200 colored images), I want to use "Principal Component Analysis" for image classification.
previously I used Resnet to predict to which class each image belong. but now I want to use the PCA.

I am trying to apply that with code, any help please?

previously I used Resnet to predict to which class each image belong. but now I want to use the PCA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCA is not a method for classification. It is a dimensional reduction method that is sometimes used as a processing step.

Take a look at this [CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144439/applying-pca-to-test-data-for-classification-purposes) for some more explanation. It has an example.

(FYI, saw this because you pinged me via the MATLAB Answers forum.)

Comment: Thanks for respond, that is right, PCA is a dimensional reduction method, may be my question wasn't clear. I mean how to hire PCA for Image classification ( after using PCA for reduction, how to use the resulted data for classification)

Comment: It's difficult to know how much of the process you need explained. Doing some googling for you, I would suggest that you try to understand [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58730/apply-principal-component-analysis-pca-for-rgb-images), which explains the process pretty well.